# "DataFrame" is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

It seems to be a recurrent problem on the site but i was not able to understand any of the similar problems/topics. I'm trying to get a scatter matrix from pandas (pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix), but I get the error `DataFrame is not callable`.

Sorry to bother you, the error is maybe obvious but I'm not able to deal with it.

I'm not very familiar with pandas.

```
#Data_set is data from load_iris from sklearn.datasets, it is a bunch and it 
#has 5 keys : 'features_names','target_names','target','DESCR', 'data'


iris_df = pd.DataFrame(Data_set['data'], columns=Data_set['feature_names'])
iris_df['species'] = Data_set['target']

pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(iris_df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(10, 10))
plt.show()
```

I just want to print the scatter matrix of my data and I get the error `DataFrame is not callable` and I'm not able to understand why.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the iris_df to make sure it's not an empty set

Comment: yes it is not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get the `scatter_matrix` without any problems using the following code:

```
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
pal = sns.color_palette("cubehelix", 8)
sns.set_palette(pal)

Data_set = datasets.load_iris()

iris_df = pd.DataFrame(Data_set['data'], columns=Data_set['feature_names'])
iris_df['species'] = Data_set['target']

pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(iris_df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(10, 10))
plt.show()
```

[image: example]

There's a possibility you haven't read in the data set correctly. Check the contents of your `Data_set`.

Comment: yes it was my Data_set that wasn't correctly set up, thanks you so much for your help !! :D